# MySql Triggers to delete child records in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I have a table that stores parent and child records in it.

I was trying to create a trigger that would delete all child records when the parent is deleted:

```
Delete From tbl Where ParentId = OLD.Id
```

While I can save the trigger successfully, when deleting I get this error:

> ERROR 1442: Can’t update table ‘tbl′ in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that this is [not possible](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,144288,162197#msg-162197):

> You cannot DELETE rows in the table
>   that activated trigger.

Some other options you might think about:

1. Write application logic that deletes the parent and child rows, and call this application logic whenever you want to delete a parent record, instead of deleting it directly.
2. Cascade delete relationship on the same table, which [appears to be possible](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,398685,398685#msg-398685).
3. A cleanup process that routinely clears out orphaned child records.
4. (suggested by @Chris) Separate out the child records from the parent records by adding another table.

Comment: or 4. Separate out the child records from the parent records by adding another table.

Comment: 4 is not an option in my case. your 2nd suggestion worked for me best. Didn't know that you can do it for the same table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

s. It is possible to do a `Delete Cascade` of child records in the same table. I found [this post in the MYSQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,398685,398710#msg-398710) had the answer.  Here's how I got it to work.

1. I had to make sure that the primary id's parent was set to NULL.
2. I had to make sure that the primary id and parent id's were set to exactly the same kind of field, such as INT.
3. I also had to make sure the primary id was set to auto increment.

From the MYSQL forum:

```
create table edges(
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  parentid int,
  unique key(id, parentid),
  foreign key(parentID) references edges(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) engine=innodb; 

insert into edges(ID,parentID) values (1,null),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2);
```

Now do this and watch the parent and all children delete cascade:

```
delete from edges where id=2;

select * from edges will then show two records left.  Record 1 and record 3.
```

This was huge for my project, a gallery where users could create albums inside of albums inside of albums.