# MySQL delete specific number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm having a tough time finding a query to delete a specific number of rows in a table.  My goal is to keep the number of rows in a table to a specific number.  For example, I don't want to exceed 1 million rows.  Isn't there a way to add a trigger on insert that looks at the row count and then deletes the number of rows that exceeds 1 million?  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I tried:

```
delete from `table` where `id` not in
(select `id` from `table` order by `id` desc limit 20)
```

But, I get error code 1235, this version of mysql doesn't yet support 'limit & in/all/any/some subquery'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It should be better do that with 2 queries. One for counting the total and the second one to delete with a limit =(total - 1million)

Comment: Robert, I was trying that too, but I wasn't able to get that to work either.  I thought I could create a variable and set the value = count.  Then use this variable in the next query, but I wasn't able.  If you couldn't tell, I'm not very experience in sql stuff.  Any chance you could show an example?

Comment: Are you programming only in SQL or do you have something like PHP or Java?

Comment: My application is vb.net.  If I can't get it done in MySQL I will just do it all in .net.

Comment: So it looks like a trigger is not possible, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885715/mysql-triggers-to-delete-child-records-in-the-same-table

Comment: It looks like you can't use a variable in a limit either, however, it looks like there is a workaround: https://orkus.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/variable-limit-statement-in-mysql/.  So, I think I have a solution.

Comment: I just did all of this in vb.net. I found it easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

how about doing it by batch like

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

and just add a for loop on it.